# JSF - forwarded URL with proxy lost

Tags: apache, jsf, glassfish, ocpsoft-rewrite

When using an apache proxy against our glassfish 5 the forwarded URL data are lost.

This happens within our login *@WebFilter* and can be reproduced using a simple ajax page update with an `<h:outputText value="forward.request_uri: #{requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}" />` .

**Testcase**

This example access URL *http://localhost:3080/News*

This URL represents our *testTenant* and is proxied to: */tenant/testTenant/News* which is the rewritten version of */sites/tenant/news.xhtml?tenant=testTentant* using OCPSoft library.

The request headers *host, x-forwarded-host* are set correctly to *http://localhost:3080* on the ajax checking `#{headerValues}`.

**GET request correct in Markup**

`forward.request_uri: /News`

**AJAX request wrong in Markup**

`forward.request_uri: /tenant/testTenant/News`

**WebFilter wrong in Java**

Logging this inside the *@WebFilter*, even at the first GET request using `request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")` will give same wrong URI.

What can be the reason this is lost?

Is there a differene between `request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")` and `#{requestScoped['request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri')}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markup seemed to have the correct URI `/tenant/testTenant/News` since there was a `SUBSTITUTE` rule in the apache proxy to remove `/tenant/testTenant`.

The ajax was not correct, since the substitution was only active for `text/html` files and not for AJAX `text/xml` files.

Checking the `action` attribute of the surrounding form after the ajax request showed it was not rewritten which is a sign of a bad proxy config. Thanks to @BalusC response at: https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/370#issuecomment-299688452

So there was no error in the `@WebFilter` either since it showed the same result as the markup (which just was substituted).